# Material UI V5: createTheme Palette only works on primary and secondary

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've created a palette to pass primary and secondary colors, it works, but when i try to pass the info tag it wont work.

```
    palette: {
    mode: 'dark',
    primary: {
        main: darkprimaryColor,
    },
    secondary: {
        main: darksecondaryColor,
    },
    info: {
        main: darkinfoColor,
    },
},
```

then pass the  color on my Fab buttons

```
    <Fab size="small" variant="extended" color="primary">Share</Fab>
    <Fab size="small" variant="extended" color="secondary">Learn More</Fab>
    <Fab size="small" variant="extended" color="info">Warning</Fab>
```

The button with color "info" doesnt recorgnize.

Another question is how to pass mutiples colors on primary palette, like so:

```
"primary: {
    main: darkprimaryColor,
    darker: darkerprimaryColor,
},"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `Fab` only supports colors `primary` and `secondary`, as is said in the API docs: https://mui.com/api/fab/#props.

If you apply the `info` color to plain `Button`s, it will work:

```js
<Button color="primary" variant="contained">Button Primary</Button>
<Button color="secondary" variant="contained">Button Secondary</Button>
<Button color="info" variant="contained">Button Info</Button>
```

You can see that in the `Button` API docs as well: https://mui.com/api/button/#props.

About setting the color variants, I could do it this way:

```js
info: {
  main: '#0000bb',
  dark: '#000077',
  light: '#0000ff',
}
```

(TypeScript code hints can help with that).

Comment: Thanks for answering, It works on Button, but how i pass the color variants in the button: something like: "<Button color="info.dark" variant="contained">Button Info</Button>" ?